# Parsing Strings in SuperCSV

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

@Carlo V. Dango
I have simplified my question and I have read the documentation--good advice not to panic.  Still, I have problems.  Help me solve one and it will solve them all. Thank you.

Question:  When I have a csv record that is missing a non-String field, how (or even can I) convert the missing entry to a default value, or at least, not throw NullPointerException? Optional cellProcessor doesn't appear to prevent the error either.

This the program taken essentially from the SuperCSV website.

```
package com.test.csv;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ParseBigDecimal;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ParseDate;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ParseInt;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ift.CellProcessor;
import org.supercsv.io.CsvBeanReader;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvBeanReader;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;


public class CSVReader {

private static final CellProcessor[] cellProcessor = new CellProcessor[] {
    null,
    null,
    new ParseInt(),
    new ParseDate("yyyyMMdd"),      
    new ParseBigDecimal()       
};

public static void main (String[] args ) throws Exception {

    CsvPreference pref = new CsvPreference('"', '|', "\n");

    ICsvBeanReader inFile = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader("C:\\temp\\sapfilePipe.txt"), pref);
    try {
        final String[] header = inFile.getCSVHeader(true);
        User user;
        while ((user = inFile.read(User.class, header, cellProcessor)) != null) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    } finally {
        inFile.close();
    }

}
```

}

here is the CSV file I'm reading.  Notice in the first record there is a missing field (age).

```
firstName|lastName|age|hireDate|hourlyRate
A.|Smith|  |20110101|15.50
```

My User bean:

```
package com.test.csv;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

public class User {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private Date hireDate;
private BigDecimal hourlyRate;
    ...getters/setters...
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.supercsv.io.CsvBeanReader.fillObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.supercsv.io.CsvBeanReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.glazers.csv.CSVReader.main(CSVReader.java:31)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list reader reads each line into a list of strings. It seems this is what you are looking for.

http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/CsvListReader.html

or as shown here http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html you can set the processor to null if you don't want anything specific done.

Comment: Hi... If I had a blank column that should be converted to BigDecimal, I have tried      new ParseBigDecimal(new StrReplace(" ", "0")),

Comment: When building cellprocessors, do you build from the inside out or the outside in....for example.. if I have a blank in a column that would otherwise be a quantity value, how do I chain processors to convert the blank to a 0 then use ParseBigDecimal?  I'm getting fairly desperate to understand what I'm not understanding.  Realizing I could put a null in the CellProcessor array was huge.  I interpreted as "read but not processed" in the website examples, as 'ignored' altogether.

Comment: as shown on http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/codeExamples_general.html its outside-in. It's the first example with the unique processor. Try not to panic and instead focus on reading the documentation. It was titled "Getting started" hence should have some relevance.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Update for [Super CSV 2.0.0-beta-1](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html)

Super CSV 2.0.0-beta-1 is out now. It includes many bug fixes and new features (including Maven support and a new Dozer extension for mapping nested properties and arrays/Collections).

It has also changed the way empty (`""`) columns are treated - they are now read as `null`.
This means that the `firstName` and `lastName` fields in your bean will now be `null` instead of `""` if they are not present in the CSV file.

The `Optional()` processor has been updated to cater for this - so it will still function the same way.

My suggestion of using `Token` is no longer relevant: you should use `ConvertNullTo` instead:

```
new ConvertNullTo(-1, new ParseInt())
```

---

What you *really* want is the `Optional` CellProcessor, which will only allow the next processor in the chain to execute if the column isn't empty.

So update your CellProcessor array to:

```
private static final CellProcessor[] cellProcessor = new CellProcessor[] {
    null,
    null,
    new Optional(new ParseInt()),
    new ParseDate("yyyyMMdd"),      
    new ParseBigDecimal()       
};
```

That way, `ParseInt` will only get executed if the column is not blank (CellProcessors execute from left to right), leaving the int field in the bean with its default value of 0.

If you wanted to set the field to -1 to indicate that no value was supplied, then you could use the `Token` processor, which will replace any token ("" in this case) with a desired value, for any other input it will continue to the next processor. i.e.

```
new Token("", -1, new ParseInt())
```

@Carlo V. Dango the CsvListReader is a very primitive implementation (and you lose the ability to map to beans) so I'd only use it for quick and dirty parsing.

And I'd only recommend using `null` in the array (when reading) for String properties that require no further processing.

By the way, I'm on the Super CSV project working for an upcoming release. I'll be sure to improve the code examples on the website while I'm at it ;)

Comment: Thank you very very very much for this tip.   In the instance of my original question, I went the route of making all fields strings in the bean, and parsing them out later, in my process.  I will take this sample, and run my tests against it using the input files I have to work with.  I always thought my issues were my own clumsiness in chaining the cell processors.  I love the bean reader/writers.  Our company is converting to SAP which has many opportunities for reading/writing CSV files for all the custom interfaces.  SuperCSV is a big player in our processing now.

Comment: @Davidson Great to hear you're using still using Super CSV - it's a great little API. It's been dormant for a while, but I've recently joined the project and am hoping to breathe some new life into it. If you have any more issues or ideas for new features please post on the Super CSV SourceForge forums - we'd love to hear from you. You're lucky your interface with SAP is CSV, at my work it is positional (first column is 20 chars, second is 10 chars, etc)!! By the way, if you find this helpful, could you vote/select this answer?